# Not sure how to handle a fairly involved query with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, subquery

This query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `results` (`class_id`, `rider_id`, `schedule_id`, `finish`, `points`, `season_id` )
SELECT DISTINCT racedata.class_id, riders.id as rider_id, schedule.id as schedule_id,  racedata.cf_finish, racedata.main_points, schedule.season_id
FROM (racedata LEFT JOIN riders ON racedata.ridername = riders.ridername) 
INNER JOIN `schedule` ON `schedule`.date = STR_TO_DATE(`racedata`.event_date, '%m/%d/%Y') WHERE cf_finish > 0;
```

I need to change the query so that it uses the current year as a lookup to another table called `seasons` to get the id associated with the current year. It has fields `id` and `season` which contains years.

Right now I store `season_id` in the `schedule` table, but don't want to use that field any longer. I"m trying to simplify the front end of the app, which is in turn complicating the backend.

I want to use `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())` to get the current year, it works in where statements great, but I've not used it in this context before.

Should I be trying to do a nested select inside my select to get the data I want?

Comment: Without seeing the data and the desired result (forget about the insert for now) this kind of problem is made unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I'll get a data dump later this evening. Places to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `results`
    (`class_id`, `rider_id`, `schedule_id`,
    `finish`, `points`, `season_id` )
SELECT DISTINCT racedata.class_id, riders.id as rider_id,
    schedule.id as schedule_id,  racedata.cf_finish,
    racedata.main_points, season.season_id
FROM racedata
LEFT JOIN riders
ON racedata.ridername = riders.ridername
INNER JOIN `schedule`
ON `schedule`.date = STR_TO_DATE(`racedata`.event_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
INNER JOIN `seasons`
ON `seasons`.date = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())
AND `seasons`.date = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `schedule`.date)
WHERE cf_finish > 0;
```

Comment: I'll give this a try when I get a chance. 

Thanks